# Spring WS and UDDI

Tags: java, spring, maven, uddi

I have a bunch of web services implemented in Spring-WS 1.5.9.  We use Maven to do our builds, our services run on OC4J that have a UDDI provider.

What we want to do is to start using UDDi internally to register our web services to allow other groups in the business to find and use them.

The problem is that I've not been able to find how to actually put this all together.  How do I get the services to register them selves when they are deployed to the app server.

Spring doesn't seem to have any support or annotations.  There doesn't appear to be a maven plugin.

I've got all the pieces but how do I put these together into an automated solution?

Answer (score 2):

For service discoverability, Spring-ws provides the `DestinationProvider` interface to locate the edpoint of a service at runtime. You can use the `Wsdl11DestinationProvider` class to retrieve the endpoint from a WSDL available or you can implement your own class by extending `AbstractCachingDestinationProvider` using UDDi access libraries.

For the automatic publication, I am aware of [Mule Galaxy](http://www.mulesoft.org/galaxy) wich is a Service Registry solution (not based on UDDI but on ATOM/REST) that provides connectrs to automatically import artifacts from Maven for example.

Answer (score 0):

You could use UDDI4J it let you interact with uddi servers :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out Apache jUDDI. It has annotations that youc an use to automate the registration process. I'm not sure what you mean by "internal use only" but can you run optionally run the full server in embedded mode without a web container) or it can be ran within Tomcat, Jboss, and most other containers.

Example: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/juddi/trunk/juddi-examples/uddi-annotations/

There's also a number of other solutions, such as WS-Discovery, mDNS, ebXML etc.