# Role of UDDI in Spring Web services?

Tags: java, web-services, spring-ws, uddi

I have gone thru [spring ws](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/index.html) but did not 
come across role of UDDI in spring WS. I believe spring configuration(i.e PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping)
internally publishing and finding it from UDDI . Is that correct ?

Comment: No it isn't... Spring-ws doesn't do anything with UDDI. I suggest you do a little readup on what UDDI is and what its place is in the webservice world. Little hint it is quite dead...

Comment: @M.Deinum  i have read about UDDI. My understanding is when we publish the web service(for example Endpoint.publish(..)), it gets registered with UDDI and when cosumer request comes , request is made to UDDI to discover it. Is n't that correct ?

Comment: That isn't correct... It just publishes your endpoint so that you can access it, it doesn't do anything with UDDI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, Spring doesn't explicitly cover UDDI. If you're a fan of annotations and configuration based tooling, jUDDI has it.

Example: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/juddi/tags/juddi-3.2.0/juddi-examples/wsdl2uddi-lifecyle/

Related post: [Spring WS and UDDI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248980/spring-ws-and-uddi)